# How to know if user watched ad?

Tags: android

So I am letting the user watch a video interstitial (which I set up in admob), for a point in my app. I want the user to watch the full ad to get the point, how do I implement that? I have tried this:

```
 mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                giveUserPoint();
                }
            }
        });
```

But the user doesn't even have to watch my ad using this. Using this code, the user can just X out of the ad, and `onAdClosed` will be called. How do I know if the user has fully watched my ad?

**Is there a way to hide the X button untill the ad is finished?**

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Use `@Override onRewarded` with Rewarded Video Ads**

For this, you should not use regular video interstitials. Instead, use Android's Rewarded Video Ads:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

From the docs:

> To be notified of rewarded video lifecycle events, you must implement
>   RewardedVideoAdListener. The rewarded ad listener is set using the
>   setRewardedVideoAdListener() method. This listener is automatically
>   notified of events from all the networks you're mediating. For
>   example, you are notified of a user being rewarded for watching a
>   video through the onRewarded() method on RewardedVideoAdListener.

So there are only a few steps you need to go through to achieve the desired functionality. Let me break it down.

**Step One: Create the Rewarded Ad Instance:**

```
 // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
```

**Step Two: Load the Rewarded Ad:**

```
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

**Step Three: Reward the user in the callback method:**

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}
```

In your question, you pointed out that users could simply exit the ad to take advantage of the reward. You can track/ prevent that with the other callback methods that tell you exactly how the user is interacting with your ads:

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Step Four: Now that you have the ad completely ready, just display it**

```
if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
}
```

Comment: your answer makes no sense, you are just giving general information. where in your answer, you indicate how to understand if it is fully watched? after 4secs of the video is already rewarded and onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication is never called if you click back button, X button etc. onRewardedVideoAdClosed is fired but this can happen any where in the video.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setImmersiveMode to hide X button but after 4 secs, there will be "Skip this Video" button as well which will prevent to watch entire video. But I am guessing this based on the meditation. not all videos are having this option.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAd#setImmersiveMode(boolean)